# Haskell list of int tuples to string

Tags: string, haskell, tuples

I'm trying to write out my list of tuples from:

```
[(8,7),(5,6),(3,3),(9,4),(5,4)]
```

to:

```
8 7 5 6 3 3 9 4 5 4
```

this is how far i've come:
(Updated)

```
showTuples :: Board -> String
showTuples = unwords . fmap show . concatMap (\(x,y) -> [x,y])
```

I know i'm suppose to map this function to all elements of my list but i can't seem to get it right.

(UPDATE)
It worked, still having problems with the quotation marks though

also type of Board is:

```
type Board = [(Int,Int)]
```

Comment: You should try `unwords . fmap show . concatMap (\(x,y) -> [x,y])`

Comment: Thank you, that worked great.. but i still have "" <-- those

Comment: Shouldn't `showTuple` have type `(Int, Int) -> String`, based on the name alone?

Comment: Yes i've changed it now

Comment: You need to use `putStrLn` instead of `print` if you don't want to see the quotes when you're printing the string.

Comment: It's fixed thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

Using pattern matching:

```
type Board = [(Int, Int)]

showTuples :: Board -> String
showTuples [] = ""
showTuples (x:[]) = show(fst(x)) ++ " " ++ show(snd(x))
showTuples (x:xs) = show(fst(x)) ++ " " ++ show(snd(x)) ++ " " ++ showTuples xs

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn . showTuples $ [(8, 7), (5, 6), (3, 3), (9, 4), (5, 4)] -- 8 7 5 6 3 3 9 4 5 4
```

Comment: no need to add pattern for a list with single element if you have the empty list pattern

Comment: @MrTsjolder You actually do need this extra case here because you're inserting extra space in between the numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your time, its fixed!

Comment: @ruubel If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it

Comment: I would if it did ofc, but @gallais actually helped me. I just thanked this post cause it's an alternate solution.

Comment: @gallais should add his solution as an answer so you can accept it. 

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by a `foldl` too.

```
Prelude> foldl (\r (x,y) -> r ++ " " ++ show x ++ " " ++ show y) "" [(8,7),(5,6),(3,3),(9,4),(5,4)]
" 8 7 5 6 3 3 9 4 5 4"
```

If you don't want the preceding whitespace then just do like `tail $ foldl (\r (x,y) -> ...`

Comment: Using `foldl` with `(++)` is going to be dreadfully expensive, isn't it? I don't see any reason this couldn't be a `foldr`.